# How to make iphone's keyboard never hide?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I need keyboard never hide in my view (for example as in facebook app in login form)

How can I do it?  I use

```
[textFieldEmail addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(textFieldDone:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

and when i tap done on keyboard, it hides, I tried

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender {  
[sender becomeFirstResponder];
   //...
}
```

but it doesn't help, how can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the following method of the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Also ensure you have specified the UITextField's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all that code.

Usually people have the *opposite* problem - trying to figure out how/when to *hide* they keyboard!

If you do nothing - by default - the keyboard will stay up! The "done" key should not dismiss the keyboard, unless someone, somewhere is calling "resignFirstResponder".

Comment: yes, but I need an action performed when Done is tapped, how can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a login form as in facebook, you can add a temp textfield which you can put out of window screen, and when the client click the login button, you perform a delayed selector after 0.1s. In the selector, you first make the temp textfield become the first responder and then do the login logic, so the keyboard stays now. If login failed, you just make your password textfield become first responder. In the above way, it makes sure the keyboard is always seen. Hope it help.